# Duvida ao obter o valor de um radioGroup para enviar em um email

Tags: c#, android, email, xamarin.android, radiobutton

Olá, no meu código eu tenho 4 RadioGroups e vou passar o valor deles em um e-mail. Até ai tudo bem, porém no meu código eu não estou conseguindo (não sei como fazer) mandar apenas o texto do RadioGroup que foi selecionado.

Atualmente estou meio que obrigando o usuário a escolher um radioButton de cada radiogroup (4 ao total), mas na verdade eu queria permitir o usuário a escolher apenas 1 RadioGroup e o programa vai enviar esse valor.

Por exemplo na linha abaixo, ele obriga que o usuário selecione os 4 radioGroups.

```
email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Como devo fazer para que dependendo do radiogroup que o usuário escolha, o programa obtenha o texto e o envie? Devo fazer vários **if/else** travando todas as possibilidades de combinações ou tem como fazer com um for each?

Segue abaixo o código do botão Enviar

```
void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                RadioButton rdbgrupo1 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgconquiste.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                RadioButton rdbgrupo2 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgcrie.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                RadioButton rdbgrupo3 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgviva.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                RadioButton rdbgrupo4 = FindViewById<RadioButton>(rdgentregue.CheckedRadioButtonId);
                int RadioGroupIsChecked(RadioGroup radioGroup)
                {
                    //-1 means empty selection
                    return radioGroup.CheckedRadioButtonId;
                }

                //When user doesn't check a radio button, show a Toast
                if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) == -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) == -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) == -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) == -1)
                {
                    string excecao = "Ao menos um botão deve ser selecionado e o comentário deve ser preenchido";
                    Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    String emailescolhido = spinner.SelectedItem.ToString();

                    if (emailescolhido == "Escolha um colaborador abaixo")
                    {
                        string excecao = "Por favor, escolha um colaborador";
                        Toast.MakeText(this, excecao, ToastLength.Long).Show();

                    }

                    else { 
                    String campocomentario = comentário.Text;
                        string emailchefe = "acursio_maia@whirlpool.com";
                    var email = new Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionSend);
                    //send to
                    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraEmail,
                    new string[] { "" + emailescolhido });

                    //subject
                    email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraSubject, "SABIA QUE VOCÊ FOI RECONHECIDO?");
                    //content
                    if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo2.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo3.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }

                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " +rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo3.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgconquiste) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo1.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo3.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else if (RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgcrie) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgviva) != -1 & RadioGroupIsChecked(rdgentregue) != -1)
                        {
                            email.PutExtra(Android.Content.Intent.ExtraText,
                            "Você foi reconhecido pelo(s) valor(es) de: " + rdbgrupo2.Text + " , " + rdbgrupo3.Text + " e " + rdbgrupo4.Text + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + "" + System.Environment.NewLine + campocomentario + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        email.SetType("message/rfc822");
                    StartActivity(email);
                    Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertdialog.SetTitle("Confirmação de envio");
                    alertdialog.SetMessage("Email enviado com sucesso");
                    alertdialog.SetNeutralButton("Ok", delegate {
                        alertdialog.Dispose();
                    });
                    alertdialog.Show();
                }
                }


            }


            catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
            {
                showbox(ex.Message);

            } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lucas não programo na linguagem que você esta usando mas a lógica é a seguinte

```
For each rb in rbgroup
   'se foi selecionado
   if rb.value=true then
    msgbox (rb.text)
   end if
next
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer :)